# What is the balanced equation of BH3/THF with an amide to form an amine?

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines, organic-reduction, amides

I am doing a green chemistry project as an undergraduate and need the balanced equation to complete the calculations. I cannot find the right information online so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: primary, secondary or tertiary amide? It makes a difference

Comment: Secondary amide attached to a propyl group.  Ar-C(Me)HCONHPr

Comment: Please could you tell the products produced after the reaction other than the target molecule. What does the borane complex become after the reduction? Something like HOBH2/THF or OBH/THF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reduction of secondary amides with BH3 requires 3 equivalents, mechanism shown below image sourced from [here](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0100-40422002000200018). The borane becomes HB=O which may transform further depending on work up.

[image]

Comment: I didn't understand how did the N-H become N-BH2 in the first step?